# How to forecast with FB's Prophet with one common model for multiple users' time series data?

Tags: python, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I have the following (Pandas) data frame with daily records of purchase amounts (`y`) of different users (`user_id)` with other independent features (`v1, v2`) like this:

```
ds                      user_id v1  v2  y

2013-01-01 00:00:00     user00  6   100 8
2013-01-01 00:00:00     user01  5   0   8
2013-01-01 00:00:00     user02  4   1   12
2013-01-01 00:00:00     user03  3   200 2
...
2013-12-31 00:00:00     user99  1   0   1
```

I want to make multivariate predictions (forecasts) for the next 30 days for `y` with Facebook's Prophet. I'm new to Prophet, and the tutorials I've seen so far are used to train models on the whole training set without any assumption of the possible existence of multiple users (or other entities):

```
model = Prophet()
model.add_regressor('v1', standardize=False)
model.add_regressor('v2', standardize=False)
model.fit(df_train)
```

This evidently doesn't fit to my problem above. The most fitting examples found so far are training many different models according to the different entities like this:

```
for user in set(df_train.user_id):

    model = Prophet()
    model.add_regressor('v1', standardize=False)
    model.add_regressor('v2', standardize=False)
    model.fit(df_train.loc[df_train.user_id == user])
    forecast = model.predict(...)
```

However, this also seem unfit, as I don't wish to have as many forecasting models as users (as the magnitude of users in reality are on ten thousands, and anyway, users come and leave constantly). My goal is to train one single model for all users (present and future), something like a single common LSTM neural network fit on multiple time series. But how to build this on Prophet?

(Additional question: is explicit standardization needed on features/target with Prophet?)

Comment: I am also having the same question. Did you find any further insights into it?